# Resolving service inside Main.cs registered at Startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

My question is: is it possible to resolve a service in the main.cs of a Web Api application (.net core) ?
What I usually do is always of course registering all the services at Startup and inject them wherever needed.

I am in a situation where I have only 1 web api application exposing some REST controllers. Whenever this application starts I would like it to start doing something in the background.
For this reason I would like to get an instance of a service I registered in Startup and call it within Main.cs.

My pretty plain Main.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting web host");
        webHostBuilder.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You could use IHostedService to start in the background or access the host's Services

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: @Nkosi services registered at Startup in ConfigureServices get resolved and injected through DI wherever needed (the instance itself gets injected). I would like to know how to resolve a service and get its instance from Main if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put application startup logic in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786605/where-to-put-application-startup-logic-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @devNull yes and no.. the line **(IServiceScopeFactory)webHost.Services.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory));** does but the rest of the question is for a different purpose. I don't want to execute something before **Run**.. or at least I want it but not in that way to block the **Run** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming of your `webHostBuilder` is inaccurate. `CreateHostBuilder(args);` returns a builder. But once the web host builder has been built via `.Build()` you have access to [`IWebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost) which exposes `IServiceProvider` via the `Services` property

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebHost webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    IServiceProvider services = webHost.Services; //services can be used to manually resolve
    IMyService myService = services.GetService<IMyService>();

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting web host");
        webHost.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

But I get the impression that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> Whenever this application starts I would like it to start doing something in the background.

This could be achieved via hosted services

Reference [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services)

Comment: exactly what I needed ! Just to specify: I think I need to install **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions** package in order to use that GetService method the way you do. Am I right? also to learn something more: why was my naming wrong? Thanks once more!

Comment: @Tarta the name `webHostBuilder` implies that the variable holds a builder not the host.

Comment: @Tarta check included link in the answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I thank you in advance for your link! Didn't know about Worker Services. I also understand your doubt about XY problem and maybe you are right. The situation is the following: I have an API service. When this starts I need to start scraping an external API and start feeding a simple dictionary. While scraping my API serves an endpoint that can read what's so far in the dictionary. If I use your Worker Service where do I store this data structure (Dictionary) ? In the Worker Service itself ? And when I request it from my app I just access it there?